# pyscripter reclassify error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, reclassify, pyscripter

I am new to python, so bear with me. 
Trying running reclassify in pyscripter returns the error:

Message File Name   Line    Position
Traceback
           21
    Reclassify  C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py   5236
    swapper C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py   47
    wrapper C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py   5230
        C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py    498
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to open raster dataset
Failed to execute (Reclassify).

My code is simple, and it works in the python window in arcmap, so I am guessing it has something to do with how i set pyscripter up. I successfully tried SplineWithBarriers, so it is working:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "V:/USER/b/Processing"

# Set local variables
inRaster = "barr7"
reclassField = "VALUE"
remap =  RemapValue([[1,9],[2,8],[3,1],[4,6],[5,3],[6,3],[7,1]])

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Execute Reclassify
outReclassify = Reclassify(inRaster, reclassField, remap, "NODATA")
```

Comment: I am not using geodatabases. The save part is not responsible for the error, so i removed it from the question.

Comment: Yes, its a file of type: "File System Raster". In the python window in ArcMap it is not necessary to specify more.

Comment: so what should i add to the barr7?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58175/discussion-between-jeppe-olsen-and-mr-che).

Comment: My comments are deleted. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this script and it work well, try to use it as an example:

```
import arcpy

inRaster = r"G:\TEST_DEL\raster.tif"
outRaster = r"G:\TEST_DEL\raster_out.tif"

reclassField = "VALUE"
remap = arcpy.sa.RemapValue([[0,9999]])

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

outReclassify = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(inRaster, reclassField, remap, "NODATA")
outReclassify.save(outRaster)

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
```

[image]

Comment: This works, not sure why though. You put in r before filenames and arcpy.sa. before RemapValue. But thanks.